# Angular testing with Jest - issue with triggerEventHandler

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I have a setup where I'm writing an Angular application, and testing it with JEST.

Everything seems to be working, until I try to imitate event-interactions in Angular. The following test does indeed work:

```js
it('should delegate click to component', () => {
  jest.spyOn(component, 'add');
  const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button > fa-icon[icon="plus"]'));
  button.nativeElement.click();
  expect(component.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However, when I try to use fixture's `triggerEventHandler('click', null)`-method, the spy is never invoked.

```js
it('should delegate click to component', () => {
  jest.spyOn(component, 'add');
  const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button > fa-icon[icon="plus"]'));
  button.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
  expect(component.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I did try to wrap it in `fakeAsync`, invoke `tick()` (and `flush()`, for that matter) but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

The major issue is not with this case... since I can trigger the event on the native element, the bigger issue is when I have to test custom event bindings.

Does anybody have any idea why using the native element's `click`-function works (I've read that it uses the DOM's native event bubling), but using the fixture's `triggerEventHandler`does not? Even more important, how can I fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

**Additional info**

I'm using the following jest configuration (copied from `package.json`):

```
"jest": {
"preset": "jest-preset-angular",
"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts",
"verbose": true,
"testURL": "http://localhost/",
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(ts|html)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/preprocessor.js",
  "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(@ngrx|ngx-bootstrap))"
],
"globals": {
  "ts-jest": {
    "tsConfigFile": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
    "useBabelrc": true
  },
  "__TRANSFORM_HTML__": true
}
```

}

Comment: I got a similar issue, did you progress ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how exactly your button click handler works, but bear in mind that `button.nativeElement.click()` is not exactly the same as `button.triggerEventHandler('click', null)`. The former will have a real event object with target, the latter will have what you specify, i.e. `null`, so you should at the very least use:

```
  button.triggerEventHandler('click', { target: button.nativeElement })
```

but I don't see why you should use `triggerEventHandler` over `nativeElement.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because my click handler was attempting to access a property on the event, which was causing a null pointer exception. I fixed it by passing an actual event object to triggerEventHandler instead of null.

```js
it('should delegate click to component', () => {
  jest.spyOn(component, 'add');
  const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button > fa-icon[icon="plus"]'));
  button.triggerEventHandler('click', new Event('click'));
  expect(component.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```